# Toolbar com duas cores diferentes

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbar, cores

Como fazer uma toolbar com duas cores pela metade, indo de uma cor para a outra?

[image: Uma barra de título de uma aplicação chamada Via Universitária, com o título sobre um fundo em efeito gradiente, indo do rosa para o roxo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O nome desse efeito é *Dégradé* (degradê) ou *Gradient* (gradiente). Pra usar um gradiente como fundo da sua barra, basta criar um XML com os dados dele na pasta Drawable e usá-lo como `background` da barra. No seu caso, o XML seria algo assim (troque pelas cores exatas que você quer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#E81DCA"
        android:endColor="#7566E3"
        android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

Presumindo que chamamos o arquivo de gradiente_rosa_para_roxo.xml, o uso fica assim:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/gradiente_rosa_para_roxo"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Resultado:

[image: Uma captura de tela de um celular Android mostrando apenas a barra superior de um aplicativo com o texto "Via Universitária" no título e um efeito gradiente indo do rosa para o roxo como fundo da barra]

Comment: cara muito obrigado,me ajudou muito